# Remove progress view from all the table view cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm adding a circular custom progress view to all the table view cells like below.

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// progressView =  (M13ProgressViewPie *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

progressView = [[M13ProgressViewPie alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 5.0)];
progressView.tag = indexPath.row;

NSLog(@"%ld",(long)progressView.tag);
// Configure the progress view here.
[progressView setAnimationDuration:10.0];

// Add it to the view.
[cell.contentView addSubview: progressView];

// Update the progress as needed
[progressView setProgress: 1.0 animated: YES];
```

I want to reload the circular progress after nstimer of 10 seconds

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateUI) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and in updateUI method I'm removing the cell content view subviews.

With this I'm only able to reload the last cell progress view. It is not applying for all the cells.

Comment: share some code .

Comment: in update UI method : NSArray* subviews = [cell.contentView subviews];
    for (M13ProgressView* subview in subviews) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

Comment: where is the start timer ? in while adding  ?

Comment: i am adding it in view did load

Comment: ok and  how to get cell in updateUI function ?

Comment: TokenTableViewCell *cell;        [cell.contentView subviews]; for (M13ProgressView* subview in subviews) { [subview removeFromSuperview]; }

Comment: please put full line of TokenTableViewCell cell .

Comment: • Add a boolean property to your model. • Depending on that property add or remove the subview in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. • To remove all subviews set the property in all items of the data source to false and reload the table view.

Answer (score 0):

in CellForRowAtIndextPath

---

```
if(isProgressRemove) {
    NSArray* subviews = [cell.contentView subviews];
    for (UIView *view in subviews) {
        if((view isKindOfClass:[M13ProgressView class])) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        } 
    }
}
```

in ViewDidLoad

---

```
- (void)updateUI {
    isProgressRemove = yes;
    [self.tableView reload];
    isProgressRemove = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has big problem. You add many progress views to same cell. It happened because the table view reuses the cells without modifications.
If cell is reused,  you'll add second progress view to it. You should check in this method does cell contain progress view. For example, you can use this code:

```
<...>
UIView* currentProgressView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
if (currentProgressView)
{
  //remove or update progress value
}
else
{
  //create if needed
}
<...>
```